# Amazon cert SHA-1 signed?

Tags: certificates

I just checked Amazon's certificate and it shows it is SHA-1 signed. But Chrome does not show any warnings, like it does (the red cross) for other websites with SHA-1 signed certificates.

Am I looking at this wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome is flagging SHA-1 signed certs based on their expiration date.

For the full details on the different dates and indicators, please review:

http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html

The cert Amazon has deployed expires Oct 2nd, 2015.
[image]

Comment: Awesome! Nitty gritty detail.

Comment: @k1DBLITZ [This question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91446/why-is-google-still-using-a-sha1-certificate-on-its-own-site-when-they-are-phasi) has some very comprehensive discussion on the sunsetting of sha-1 on major sites.